# Estimate an overall correlation from the correlations within subgroups

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis

Assume that you are working with variables $x$ and $y$ divided into groups two groups, $g_1$ and $g_2$.  You know the following information:

1. The number of people within groups $g_1$ and $g_2$, labeled $n_1$ and $n_2$
2. The subgroup correlations $r_{xy_1}$ and $r_{xy_2}$ (the correlations between $x$ and $y$ within the subgroups $g_1$ and $g_2$)
3. (Optionally) the means $m_{x_1}$ and $m_{x_2}$ (the means of $x$ within $g_1$ and $g_2$) and  $m_{y_1}$ and $m_{y_2}$ (the means of $y$ within $g_1$ and $g_2$)
4. (Optionally) the standard deviations $sd_{x_1}$ and $sd_{x_2}$ (the standard deviations of $x$ within $g_1$ and $g_2$) and  $sd_{y_1}$ and $sd_{y_2}$ (the standard deviations of $y$ within $g_1$ and $g_2$)

How would one derive the overall correlation $r_{xy}$ from the above information about each of the subgroups?

Comment: Is this for some subject?

Comment: No, it's for a meta-analysis I'm conducting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need 1. through 4. to compute the overall correlation for the two groups combined. The equation for this is: $$r_{xy} = \frac{n_1 sd_{x_1} sd_{y_1} r_{xy_1} + n_1 \delta_{x_1} \delta_{y_1} + n_2 sd_{x_2} sd_{y_2} r_{xy_2} + n_2 \delta_{x_2} \delta_{y_2}}{\sqrt{n_1 (sd_{x_1}^2 + \delta_{x_1}^2) + n_2 (sd_{x_2}^2 + \delta_{x_2}^2)} \sqrt{n_1 (sd_{y_1}^2 + \delta_{y_1}^2) + n_2 (sd_{y_2}^2 + \delta_{y_2}^2)}},$$ where $$\delta_{x_1} = m_{x_1} - m_x$$ and $$\delta_{x_2} = m_{x_2} - m_x$$ are the deviations of the group means for variable $x$ from the overall mean for that variable, which we can compute with $$m_x = \frac{n_1 m_{x_1} + n_2 m_{x_2}}{n_1 + n_2}$$ and $$\delta_{y_1} = m_{y_1} - m_y$$ and $$\delta_{y_2} = m_{y_2} - m_y$$ are the deviations of the group means for variable $y$ from the overall mean for that variable, which we can compute with $$m_y = \frac{n_1 m_{y_1} + n_2 m_{y_2}}{n_1 + n_2}.$$ Note that the equation above assumes that we have computed the variances (and hence, the standard deviations) with $n_1$ and $n_2$ in the denominator (instead of $n_1 - 1$ and $n_2 - 1$).

So, let's actually try this out. Here is an example (R code):

```
library(MASS)

set.seed(12315)

### data for group 1
n1 <- 10
N1 <- mvrnorm(n1, mu=c(0,0), Sigma=matrix(c(1,.5,.5,1), nrow=2))
r1 <- cor(N1)[1,2]

### data for group 2
n2 <- 20
N2 <- mvrnorm(n2, mu=c(2,2), Sigma=matrix(c(1,.3,.3,1), nrow=2))
r2 <- cor(N2)[1,2]

### correlations within the groups
r1
r2
```

This yields:

```
> r1
[1] 0.5853821
> r2
[1] 0.2983734
```

So, these are the correlations within the two groups.

```
### group means for each variable
mx1 <- mean(N1[,1])
my1 <- mean(N1[,2])
mx2 <- mean(N2[,1])
my2 <- mean(N2[,2])

### group SDs for each variable
sdx1 <- sd(N1[,1]) * sqrt((n1-1) / n1)
sdy1 <- sd(N1[,2]) * sqrt((n1-1) / n1)
sdx2 <- sd(N2[,1]) * sqrt((n2-1) / n2)
sdy2 <- sd(N2[,2]) * sqrt((n2-1) / n2)

### overall means for variables x and y
mx <- (n1*mx1 + n2*mx2) / (n1 + n2)
my <- (n1*my1 + n2*my2) / (n1 + n2)

### deviations of group means from overall means
dx1 <- mx1 - mx
dy1 <- my1 - my
dx2 <- mx2 - mx
dy2 <- my2 - my

### overall correlation for combined data
cor(rbind(N1,N2))[1,2]
```

This yields:

```
[1] 0.7370049
```

So, this is the overall correlation of the data when the two groups are combined. And now let's try out the equation above:

```
(n1*sdx1*sdy1*r1 + n1*dx1*dy1 + n2*sdx2*sdy2*r2 + n2*dx2*dy2) / (sqrt(n1*(sdx1^2+dx1^2) + n2*(sdx2^2+dx2^2)) * sqrt(n1*(sdy1^2+dy1^2) + n2*(sdy2^2+dy2^2)))
```

This yields:

```
[1] 0.7370049
```

Exactly the same.

If you need a reference for the equation:

Dunlap, J. W. (1937). Combinative properties of correlation coefficients. *Journal of Experimental Education, 5*(3), 286-288.

It's equation (13) in the article. The generalization to more than two groups is also given (equation 14).

Comment: This answer is wonderfully comprehensive, as usual, @Wolfgang.  Thanks also for the great Dunlap reference.  I had suspected that the overall correlation depended on the distance between the group means.