# Combine Correlations over globe to get overall correlation

Tags: time-series, correlation, spatial

I realize this question might be confusing, so I'd first like to explain my setup: Imagine you have the earth split into grids. At each gridpoint there is a vector, and let's imagine I have two Dataframes in this format.
For simplicity let's assume those are recorded windspeeds and temperature at different timepoints(they aren't but who cares, it adds to interpretability).
So DF_1 has the windspeeds for each latitude and longitude combination at different time points, and DF_2 also has for example temperature at the same latitude, longitude and timepoints (the measurements are made at the same time points).

A straightforward thing to implement is getting the correlation between temperature and windspeed separately for each latitude and longitude combination, two simple sapply statements.
Let's say from this we get a Correlation matrix corr_matrix where the rows and columns are the latitude and longitude coordinates, and the values are the correlation coefficients between temperature and windspeed.

Now the question I am asking myself is, how can I combine all these values in a single number? The values are clearly not independent (if in city A the temperature is high and it's windy today, it's probably also in city B- at least if city B is geographically close), so a simple averaging won't do.
I was thinking about the Median, but have no way of justifying that. Why not the mean? (luckily so far Median and mean are very close).

I am seriously out of ideas and appreciate any help.

P.S: I have seen posts like this [overall correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132851/estimate-an-overall-correlation-from-the-correlations-within-subgroups), but so far not found an answer.
If you're wondering why even summarise all of it in a single number: There are lots of different pairs of variables (wind, temperature, pressure, rain,...) and reporting a matrix for each combination is not practicable.
The single number is supposed to supply some reasonable summary of overall "dependence" between the two variables. For example, if the "Single_Number" between Temperature and Wind is higher than between Temperature and Pressure, the Linear dependence between those two variables is also higher.

Comment: This question lacks important information: what is this "single number" intended to tell you?

Comment: I added a description: The single number is supposed to supply some reasonable summary of overall "dependence" between the two variables. For example, if the "Single_Number" between Temperature and Wind is higher than between Temperature and Pressure, the Linear dependence between those two variables is also higher.

Comment: You could start out with making a map of the local correlations